# Can R-410A refrigerant be substituted for R-134A in cars?

Tags: ac, part-interchange, refrigerant

Can R-410A refrigerant be substituted for R-134A in cars?

[image]
<sup>Figure1-4:R-410A of [*Refrigerant Charging and Service Procedures for Air Conditioning*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9654)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Only in vehicles which are specifically designed for it and I believe there are none currently in existence.

Automobiles today use R134a and in the (distant) past they used R12.

But no, you cannot substitute R410A for either R134a or R12.

Comment: "_you cannot substitute R410A for either R134a or R12_" What would happen if I did?

Comment: Most likely the system would not working properly and you would also probably cause damage to it.  A/C system components are designed with the specific characteristics of the refrigerant.  Using a refrigerant with different characteristics will cause problems.

Comment: These two refrigerants do have very different boiling points.

Comment: If you compare typical vehicle operating temperatures and correlate both refrigerant temperature/pressure charts, you'll see a dramatic difference in evaporator pressures (above 32F) and high side pressures (using 125F discharge temps as measured at condenser coil input). Vehicle r134a systems are designed not exceeding max temps (approx. 450F and pressure (approx. 550 psi). Components designed for maximums with a safety factor to ensure long life in vehicles all over the world. If you understand refrigerant temp/press charts, you're likely not going to risk damage using incorrect refrigerant.